# Monitor requests going from JBoss installed in EC2 instance

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, jboss, captcha, simplecaptcha

I have two EC2 instances both have JBoss installed there are same application installed on JBoss server. In the application it use com.captcha.botdetect.web.servlet.SimpleCaptchaServlet to get captcha. In a one EC2 instance it load correctly. On the other EC2 it give error.
If specifically said Request going to https://.../.../captcha-endpoint?get=image&c=captchaUserStyle&t=d982150e61d3487791212493d8db6977 fails while giving,

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.awt.Font.createGlyphVector(java.awt.font.FontRenderContext, String)" because the return value of "java.util.Map.get(Object)" is null`

So I started tracing the error and need to monitor weather it correctly load image from SimpleCaptchaServlet.
My doubt is due to EC2 configuration request to get image is not successful.

Need a way to monitor requests and response going from EC2